# Passing a reactive value to a plotting function as argument

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am trying to pass a reactive value derived from the *selectizeInput* **select1** to a plotting function. The reactive value itself is dependent on input from *awesomeRadio* **radio1**.

Unfortunately, passing this value to the plot function does not work, although it's accessible by renderText(). Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
##### plot function ------------------------ 
plot_function <- function(highlight){
  plot(1:9)
  points(x=c(1:9)[highlight],
         y=c(1:9)[highlight],
         col="red")
}

##### ui ------------------------ 
header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Title",
  titleWidth = 500
)
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
           box(title = "Plot 1",
               plotOutput("plot1", height = 300)
               ),
           box(width = NULL, status = "warning",
               awesomeRadio(inputId = "radio1",
                            label = "Radio1",
                            choices = c("Option1","Option2"),
                            inline = TRUE,
                            status="primary"
               ),br(),
               uiOutput("select1"))
    ),
    column(width = 3,
           box(width = NULL, status = "warning",
               textOutput(outputId = "option1")),
           box(width = NULL, status = "warning",
               textOutput(outputId = "option2")))
  )
)
ui = dashboardPage(
  header,
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  body
)

##### server ------------------------ 
server =   function(input, output) { 
  onSessionEnded(stopApp)

  choices = reactive({
    if (input$radio1=="Option1") {
      1:4
    } else if (input$radio1=="Option2") {
      5:8
    }
  })
  output$select1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("select1", label="Select1",
                   choices=choices())
                   })

  tmp = reactive({input$radio1})
  tmp2 = reactive({input$select1})
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot_function(highlight = tmp2()))
  output$option1 = renderText(paste(tmp()))
  output$option2 = renderText(paste(tmp2()))
}
##### ui ------------------------ 
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Also, I don't quite understand the different behavior of **tmp** and **tmp2**, since passing *tmp* to the plot function would work. 
Thank you for any help!

Comment: In `plot_function` `highlight` get passed as a character, so x and y end up as NAs try `c(2:9)["2"]` in R console, use `as.numeric(highlight)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few changes in your code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 4,
             box(title = "Plot 1",
                 plotOutput("plot1", height = 300)
             ),
             box(width = NULL, status = "warning",
                 awesomeRadio(inputId = "radio1",
                              label = "Radio1",
                              choices = c("Option1","Option2"),
                              inline = TRUE,
                              status = "primary"
                 ),br(),
                 uiOutput("select1"))
      ),
      column(width = 3,
             box(width = NULL, status = "warning",
                 textOutput(outputId = "option1")),
             box(width = NULL, status = "warning",
                 textOutput(outputId = "option2")))
)
)

##### server ------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {
  onSessionEnded(stopApp)

  choices <- reactive({
    if (input$radio1 == "Option1") {
      1:4
    } else if (input$radio1 == "Option2") {
      5:8
    }
  })
  output$select1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("sel", label = "Select1",
                   choices = choices())
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(1:9)
    points(x = c(1:9)[as.numeric(input$sel)],
           y = c(1:9)[as.numeric(input$sel)],
           col = "red")
  })
  output$option1 <- renderText(input$radio1)
  output$option2 <- renderText(input$sel)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```